# Apache Spark SQL: COALESCE NULL array into empty struct array

Tags: apache-spark

I have query

```sql
SELECT foo FROM bar;
```

Foo in this case is an array of structs that can be NULL. I would like to coalesce it into an empty array.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(foo, array()) FROM bar;
```

When I do that I get an error that there is a mismatch.

```
cannot resolve 'coalesce(foo, array())' due to data type mismatch: input to function coalesce should all be the same type, ...
```

The struct has about 25 fields so if possible I don't want to manually define them unless there is no other way. The reason why I don't want NULL is because when I write it to JSON I want the field to be an empty array and with NULL it's missing completely.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use SQL or can you write scala code?

Comment: Would be nice if I could keep it in SQL but it's not a hard requirement.

Comment: `CAST(array() AS array<struct<a:string, b: long>>)` or whatever type you need.

Comment: @user10938362 Can you make your comment an answer to this question. I was trying to avoid having to define the whole struct again but if I get no other answer I'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: The solution above actually doesn't work.  An empty array is considered to have type` array<string>` so the cast will fail